# Securing / Protecting a Website Administration area

Tags: security, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I'm trying to lock down a website administration area, first things first I need to add session check to an Application.cfm! This should handle all CFM files, regardless of location.

But what do I do about CSS, JS and HTML files being accessed directly?

Any other security suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by CSS, JS and HTML files being accessed directly? Those files will always be visible to your users and there is no way around it. If the browser can understand it then the user can understand it too.

Comment: So we cannot protect the likes of domain/admin/assets/stylesheet.css if a user is not logged in?

Comment: You _can_ protect those (in various ways); the question is do you _need_ to? What does a stylesheet contain that is sensitive?

Comment: I guess my main concern is the CFM files, I just wanted to be thorough - if non CFM files cannot create a security breach then I suppose I don't need to.

Comment: It's not non-CFM files you want to consider, it's static vs scripting. HTML, CSS, JS files are all static files - they don't _do_ anything on the server, can't obtain data from the database, etc.

Comment: (Of course, if your JS files contain AJAX/REST requests, the target of those needs to be appropriately secured. This is _probably_ covered by your CFML security, but potentially outside of a normal Application, so worth checking.)

Comment: Thanks I was just mulling over AJAX, if they try to make an AJAX call to the cfc which is sitting in a subfolder of 'admin' then the Application.cfm security check should handle it I assume.

Comment: Assume nothing.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: What Dan says - it _should_ handle it, but don't assume it will; make sure it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any static files (html, jpg, css, pdf, mdb(lol), etc) can be secured by placing them outside the web root and using `cfheader` and `cfcontent` to access the files. Your CFM file with `cfheader` and `cfcontent` should be covered by your application security.

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=myAwesomeAccessDatabaseIsTheBombDigity.mdb">
<cfcontent type="application/x-msacces" file="c:\NotMyWebsite\myAwesomeAccessDatabaseIsTheBombDigity.mdb">
```

Doing this with an `HTML` file is kind of silly though because the linked assets (CSS, JS, JPG, etc) won't be accessible if they are also below your web root.  Html, css, js, images (unless you're running a graphic sales website) don't usually need to be protected like that.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that this causes requests to go via CF - rather than just the web server - thus increasing load. Not a problem for occasional use, but something to be aware of if regularly used (as it might be if sending CSS/JS via it).

Comment: Oh, and whenever doing cfcontent like this, you should generally either send no-cache headers (if caching not wanted), or send appropriate expires headers, and detect/handle If-Modified-Since and respond with 304 not modified.

Comment: Good tip on the caching. I didn't mention server security because it may not be an option on a shared server or handling security outside of the application just isn't an option.  assuming the ability is there and securing those files is a must, doing so at the OS level is certainly doable.

Comment: Just for a bit of background - It's a fairly high profile website, they have their own infrastructure and host their own applications.